# Encrypted text related to murdered Scottish king or queen

Tags: cipher

The following image should lead to a 4-digit numeric code.

[image]

The hints given were as follows:

> Linlithgow

and

> A Scottish king or queen was murdered over letters like this

I've made some progress, but I have no idea if it's in the right direction, so I don't know if I should post them, given that they might throw people on the wrong trail.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! All questions here from other sources must be properly sourced, with a link to the original creator if possible. (Apologies for the inaccurate "off-topic" message - this question isn't off-topic, but for technical reasons that's the text that shows up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the [Babington cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babington_Plot), an assassination plot on Queen Elizabeth and led to the execution of Mary, Queen of Scots. Here is a helpful table:[image]
>  It's a simple substitution cipher, so we can find the symbols in this table to get: **UNDER THE PHONE**, presumably the location where you can get the 4-digit code (or at least get one step closer).